# How to combine bar and line chart in ggplot2 in R with proper scales

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

so I have a data frame df with three columns:

```
Date <- c("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June")
Number_of_events <- c(2, 4, 15, 1, 1,7)
length_of_days <- (102, 103, N/A, 250, 260, 300)
```

I want to create a bar graph with ggplot with Date as the x-axis and Number_of_events as the y axis, and a line graph with Date as the x-axis and length_of_days as the y-axis. Essentially I want them as one graph there they share the same x-axis, but have different y-axes. I am able to create the bar graph, but I cannot figure out how to put the line graph on the same plot without it looking weird because the second y-axis is so much larger than the primary axis. I also don't know how to make it so the line graph skips the N/A value in length_of_days for March so it can go straight from February to April.

Any ideas?

my code so far

```
ggplot(df) +
+ geom_bar(aes(x=Date, y=Number_of_events), stat="identity") +
+ geom_line(aes(x=Date, y=length_of_events), stat="identity", size = 1.5, color="black", group=1) +
+ scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*10, name ="Length of Event"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Date <- c("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June")
Number_of_events <- c(2, 4, 15, 1, 1,7)
length_of_days <- c(102, 103, NA, 250, 260, 300)

library(tidyverse)
data.frame(Date = factor(Date, levels = month.name),
           Number_of_events,
           length_of_days) %>%
  ggplot(data = ., aes(Date)) +
  geom_col(aes(y = Number_of_events)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = length_of_days/20, group = 1),
            data = . %>% filter(!is.na(length_of_days))) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*20, name ="Length of Event"))
```

- make the months a `factor` that is ordered chronologically
- ggplot2's secondary axes are just "decoration," so we'll need to scale the line values down and reflect the inverse transformation on the secondary axis labels
- use `group` so that ggplot2 treats the values for the line as one series, even though the x axis is factors (by default interpreted to be separate data points)
- filter out the NA to make the line layer skip the missing value

[image]